# M-S Matrix Recording

Tags: mid-side, audience

Hi All,

I am looking at doing some M-S recording for some of the live shows I produce for audience reactions. This isn't dependant on a camera as most of the audio is generally used in podcasting and radio formats.

The plan is that I will use a omni for the mid channel, a figure 8 in the side channel which is fairly standard. Then also mix in wireless handhelds in mono from the presenters that will be wondering around the audience (think about the audience in a circle). The whole thing will be done to a stereo file, not separate channels.

Will having the handhelds directly put into the mix screw up the M-S recording? My logic says no, and the stereo image should be fine and collapse to mono without any issue. Am I missing anything here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're recording the decoded M-S tracks as stereo, and add the handhelds in dead center there will be no problems with the mix, and mono-compatibility will be retained.

I don't know if it is an option, but you could think about recording the M-S channels without decoding, and adding the handhelds to the M-channel. That way you have control over the stereo image of the audience afterwards, while the handhelds will remain in the center no matter what you do.

Comment: @EMV Yeah, the that is what I plan to do, obviously I wasn't clear. Great o know that it will work. Obviously I'll test before going into the field.

Answer (score 1):

There should not be any problems if you decode the m/s before adding the extra voice channels.

However there will be the normal phase problems if the presenter ever comes close to the m/s mics and his or her voice is picked up by both.  The general rule for radio is if the mics are close try and only have one open mic at a time.

Comment: Good point, the presenters will be walking around the audience, so they will be captured by the M-S setup but their mics will be added to the Mid Channel. Hopefully this should be fine.